# How do i post a select options from a select list where i have also ticked on a check box with html/php?

Tags: php, html

I find myself stuck with a problem which i hope there is an easy solution for.

I have several check boxes and each check box has two drop down lists which are start time and end time.

i need to be able to select a start and end time and click the check box and be able to send through the info to a post screen for emailing.

I can send through all the items i checked but im having problems sending through the items in the drop down.

Im pretty sure i am missing something simple.

It needs to be able to send only times for the boxes ticked. 
Im not sure how to go about doing this and any advice or direction would help.

this is my select page with the drop downs and check boxes.

```
<form name="myForm" action="SendMail.php" method="post"enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="container">
<form>



            <h2>Options</h2>

    <div>


<select name='StarttimeOption'> 
                         <option value='No Time'> Select Time Start </option>
                         <option value='07:00'> 07:00  </option>
                         <option value='07:15'> 07:15 </option>
                         <option value='07:30'> 07:30 </option>
                         <option value='07:45'> 07:45  </option>
                         <option value='08:00'> 08:00  </option>
                         <option value='08:15'> 08:15 </option>
                         <option value='08:30'> 08:30 </option>
                         <option value='08:45'> 08:45  </option>
                         <option value='09:00'> 09:00  </option>
                         <option value='09:15'> 09:15 </option>  </select>

                         <select name='EndtimeOption'> <option value='No Time'> Select Time End </option>
                         <option value='07:00'> 07:00  </option>
                         <option value='07:15'> 07:15 </option>
                         <option value='07:30'> 07:30 </option>
                         <option value='07:45'> 07:45  </option>
                         <option value='08:00'> 08:00  </option>
                         <option value='08:15'> 08:15 </option>
                         <option value='08:30'> 08:30 </option>
                         <option value='08:45'> 08:45  </option>
                         <option value='09:00'> 09:00  </option>
                         <option value='09:15'> 09:15 </option>  </select>

                     <input   type="checkbox" name="codes[]" value="39001 - Limbs : Finger,Toe">
                     option 1</div>
            <div>


<select name='StarttimeOption'> 
                         <option value='No Time'> Select Time Start </option>
                         <option value='07:00'> 07:00  </option>
                         <option value='07:15'> 07:15 </option>
                         <option value='07:30'> 07:30 </option>
                         <option value='07:45'> 07:45  </option>
                         <option value='08:00'> 08:00  </option>
                         <option value='08:15'> 08:15 </option>
                         <option value='08:30'> 08:30 </option>
                         <option value='08:45'> 08:45  </option>
                         <option value='09:00'> 09:00  </option>
                         <option value='09:15'> 09:15 </option>  </select>

                         <select name='EndtimeOption'> <option value='No Time'> Select Time End </option>
                         <option value='07:00'> 07:00  </option>
                         <option value='07:15'> 07:15 </option>
                         <option value='07:30'> 07:30 </option>
                         <option value='07:45'> 07:45  </option>
                         <option value='08:00'> 08:00  </option>
                         <option value='08:15'> 08:15 </option>
                         <option value='08:30'> 08:30 </option>
                         <option value='08:45'> 08:45  </option>
                         <option value='09:00'> 09:00  </option>
                         <option value='09:15'> 09:15 </option>  </select>

                       <input type="checkbox" name="codes[]" value="39003 - Limbs : Limb per region "> 
                       option 2</div>
            <div>


<select name='StarttimeOption'> 
                         <option value='No Time'> Select Time Start </option>
                         <option value='07:00'> 07:00  </option>
                         <option value='07:15'> 07:15 </option>
                         <option value='07:30'> 07:30 </option>
                         <option value='07:45'> 07:45  </option>
                         <option value='08:00'> 08:00  </option>
                         <option value='08:15'> 08:15 </option>
                         <option value='08:30'> 08:30 </option>
                         <option value='08:45'> 08:45  </option>
                         <option value='09:00'> 09:00  </option>
                         <option value='09:15'> 09:15 </option>  </select>

                         <select name='EndtimeOption'> <option value='No Time'> Select Time End </option>
                         <option value='07:00'> 07:00  </option>
                         <option value='07:15'> 07:15 </option>
                         <option value='07:30'> 07:30 </option>
                         <option value='07:45'> 07:45  </option>
                         <option value='08:00'> 08:00  </option>
                         <option value='08:15'> 08:15 </option>
                         <option value='08:30'> 08:30 </option>
                         <option value='08:45'> 08:45  </option>
                         <option value='09:00'> 09:00  </option>
                         <option value='09:15'> 09:15 </option>  </select>

                       <input type="checkbox" name="codes[]" value="39005 - Limbs : Smith-Petersen or equivalent control, in theatre">
                       option 3</div>
            <div>


<select name='StarttimeOption'> 
                         <option value='No Time'> Select Time Start </option>
                         <option value='07:00'> 07:00  </option>
                         <option value='07:15'> 07:15 </option>
                         <option value='07:30'> 07:30 </option>
                         <option value='07:45'> 07:45  </option>
                         <option value='08:00'> 08:00  </option>
                         <option value='08:15'> 08:15 </option>
                         <option value='08:30'> 08:30 </option>
                         <option value='08:45'> 08:45  </option>
                         <option value='09:00'> 09:00  </option>
                         <option value='09:15'> 09:15 </option>  </select>

                         <select name='EndtimeOption'> <option value='No Time'> Select Time End </option>
                         <option value='07:00'> 07:00  </option>
                         <option value='07:15'> 07:15 </option>
                         <option value='07:30'> 07:30 </option>
                         <option value='07:45'> 07:45  </option>
                         <option value='08:00'> 08:00  </option>
                         <option value='08:15'> 08:15 </option>
                         <option value='08:30'> 08:30 </option>
                         <option value='08:45'> 08:45  </option>
                         <option value='09:00'> 09:00  </option>
                         <option value='09:15'> 09:15 </option>  </select>

                       <input type="checkbox" name="codes[]" value="39007 - Limbs : Stress studies">
                       option 4</div>
            <div>


<select name='StarttimeOption'> 
                         <option value='No Time'> Select Time Start </option>
                         <option value='07:00'> 07:00  </option>
                         <option value='07:15'> 07:15 </option>
                         <option value='07:30'> 07:30 </option>
                         <option value='07:45'> 07:45  </option>
                         <option value='08:00'> 08:00  </option>
                         <option value='08:15'> 08:15 </option>
                         <option value='08:30'> 08:30 </option>
                         <option value='08:45'> 08:45  </option>
                         <option value='09:00'> 09:00  </option>
                         <option value='09:15'> 09:15 </option>  </select>

                         <select name='EndtimeOption'> <option value='No Time'> Select Time End </option>
                         <option value='07:00'> 07:00  </option>
                         <option value='07:15'> 07:15 </option>
                         <option value='07:30'> 07:30 </option>
                         <option value='07:45'> 07:45  </option>
                         <option value='08:00'> 08:00  </option>
                         <option value='08:15'> 08:15 </option>
                         <option value='08:30'> 08:30 </option>
                         <option value='08:45'> 08:45  </option>
                         <option value='09:00'> 09:00  </option>
                         <option value='09:15'> 09:15 </option>  </select>

                       <input type="checkbox" name="codes[]" value="39009 - Limbs : Length studies per right and left pair of long bones">
                       option 5</div>
            <div>


<select name='StarttimeOption'> 
                         <option value='No Time'> Select Time Start </option>
                         <option value='07:00'> 07:00  </option>
                         <option value='07:15'> 07:15 </option>
                         <option value='07:30'> 07:30 </option>
                         <option value='07:45'> 07:45  </option>
                         <option value='08:00'> 08:00  </option>
                         <option value='08:15'> 08:15 </option>
                         <option value='08:30'> 08:30 </option>
                         <option value='08:45'> 08:45  </option>
                         <option value='09:00'> 09:00  </option>
                         <option value='09:15'> 09:15 </option>  </select>

                         <select name='EndtimeOption'> <option value='No Time'> Select Time End </option>
                         <option value='07:00'> 07:00  </option>
                         <option value='07:15'> 07:15 </option>
                         <option value='07:30'> 07:30 </option>
                         <option value='07:45'> 07:45  </option>
                         <option value='08:00'> 08:00  </option>
                         <option value='08:15'> 08:15 </option>
                         <option value='08:30'> 08:30 </option>
                         <option value='08:45'> 08:45  </option>
                         <option value='09:00'> 09:00  </option>
                         <option value='09:15'> 09:15 </option>  </select>

                     <input type="checkbox" name="codes[]" value=" 39011 - Limbs : Skeletal survey under 5 years">
                     option 6</div>
            <div>


             <select name='StarttimeOption'> 
                         <option value='No Time'> Select Time Start </option>
                         <option value='07:00'> 07:00  </option>
                         <option value='07:15'> 07:15 </option>
                         <option value='07:30'> 07:30 </option>
                         <option value='07:45'> 07:45  </option>
                         <option value='08:00'> 08:00  </option>
                         <option value='08:15'> 08:15 </option>
                         <option value='08:30'> 08:30 </option>
                         <option value='08:45'> 08:45  </option>
                         <option value='09:00'> 09:00  </option>
                         <option value='09:15'> 09:15 </option>  </select>

                         <select name='EndtimeOption'> <option value='No Time'> Select Time End </option>
                         <option value='07:00'> 07:00  </option>
                         <option value='07:15'> 07:15 </option>
                         <option value='07:30'> 07:30 </option>
                         <option value='07:45'> 07:45  </option>
                         <option value='08:00'> 08:00  </option>
                         <option value='08:15'> 08:15 </option>
                         <option value='08:30'> 08:30 </option>
                         <option value='08:45'> 08:45  </option>
                         <option value='09:00'> 09:00  </option>
                         <option value='09:15'> 09:15 </option>  </select>

                       <input type="checkbox" name="codes[]" value="39013 - Limbs : Skeletal survey over 5 years">
                       option 7</div>
            <div>


<select name='StarttimeOption'> 
                         <option value='No Time'> Select Time Start </option>
                         <option value='07:00'> 07:00  </option>
                         <option value='07:15'> 07:15 </option>
                         <option value='07:30'> 07:30 </option>
                         <option value='07:45'> 07:45  </option>
                         <option value='08:00'> 08:00  </option>
                         <option value='08:15'> 08:15 </option>
                         <option value='08:30'> 08:30 </option>
                         <option value='08:45'> 08:45  </option>
                         <option value='09:00'> 09:00  </option>
                         <option value='09:15'> 09:15 </option>  </select>

                         <select name='EndtimeOption'> <option value='No Time'> Select Time End </option>
                         <option value='07:00'> 07:00  </option>
                         <option value='07:15'> 07:15 </option>
                         <option value='07:30'> 07:30 </option>
                         <option value='07:45'> 07:45  </option>
                         <option value='08:00'> 08:00  </option>
                         <option value='08:15'> 08:15 </option>
                         <option value='08:30'> 08:30 </option>
                         <option value='08:45'> 08:45  </option>
                         <option value='09:00'> 09:00  </option>
                         <option value='09:15'> 09:15 </option>  </select>

  </select>

                       <input type="checkbox" name="codes[]" value="39015 - Limbs : Arthrography per joint">
                       option 8</div>
```

This is my post screen that sends the mail.
It can send all the items checked but it cant get the times.

```
<?php



 if($_POST && isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']))
{

    $from_email         = 'test@mail'; //from mail, it is mandatory with some hosts
    $recipient_email    = 'test@mail'; //recipient email (most cases it is your personal email)

    //Capture POST data from HTML form and Sanitize them,
    $sender_name    = filter_var($_POST["Name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //sender name
    $reply_to_email = filter_var($_POST["Radio"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //sender email used in "reply-to" header
    $subject        = filter_var($_POST["Radio"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //get subject from HTML form
    $message        = filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //message
    $Starter            = filter_var($_POST["StarttimeOption"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //Start time
    $Ender        = filter_var($_POST["EndtimeOption"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //Start time
    $End            = implode( "\r\n" .'  ', $_POST['EndtimeOption[]'] );//End Time
    $Start          = implode( "\r\n" .'  ', $_POST['StarttimeOption[]'] );//End Time

        $code = implode( "\r\n" .'  ', $_POST['codes'] );

    $FullMessage = 
                    'Hello
                    ' ."\r\n" .
                    'You have received a new form entry from ' . $_POST['Name'] . '
                    ' ."\r\n" .
                                        ' Name :   ' . $_POST['Name']. '
                    ' .
                                        'Surname :   ' . $_POST['surName']. '
                    ' .
                                        'Number :   ' . $_POST['idNumber']. '

                    ' .
                                        'Time:   ' . $_POST['StarttimeOption']. '

                    ' .
                                        'Time :   ' . $_POST['EndtimeOption']. '
                    ' ."\r\n" .
                                       ' These are the codes used :   

                    ' ."\r\n" .
                                        '  ' . $code . '
                                        ' ."\r\n" .
                                        '  ' . $End . '
                    ' ."\r\n" . 
                                                           ' These are the codes used :   

                    ' ."\r\n" .
                                        '  ' . $Start . '
                                        ' ."\r\n" .
                                        '  ' . $End . '
                    ' ."\r\n" . 

                                        ' ' . $_POST['Radiographer']. ' has attached the following comment: 

                    ' .
                               $_POST['message'];


    /* //don't forget to validate empty fields
    if(strlen($sender_name)<1){
        die('Name is too short or empty!');
    }
    */

    //Get uploaded file data
    $file_tmp_name    = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_name        = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
    $file_size        = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['size'];
    $file_type        = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['type'];
    $file_error       = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'];

    if($file_error > 0)
    {
        die('Upload error or No files uploaded');
    }
    //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content for the mail
    $handle = fopen($file_tmp_name, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

        $boundary = md5("sanwebe");
        //header
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$reply_to_email."" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n";

        //plain text
        $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
        $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($FullMessage));

        //attachment
        $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=".$file_name."\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name."\r\n";
        $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
        $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000,99999)."\r\n\r\n";
        $body .= $encoded_content;

    $sentMail = @mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
    if($sentMail) //output success or failure messages

    {     
        die('  Thank you for your email. <a href=\billing\patientDetails.php> click here to start billing a new patient</a>');

    }else{
        die('Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.');  

    }
  echo('PAge offline.'); 
}


?>
```

Comment: You need to tag this post with PHP, as well.

Comment: All your drop downs have the same name.  You probably want to give them separate names. Then use an if statement to check which check boxes are selected

Comment: @liquidacid  how/where would i use the if? can you show me an example ?

Comment: Would it be possible to put the the drop downs and the check box in a type of array ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend use javascript or jQuery to display select option to the related checkbox that way you can manage the form better. I know my answer is not what you're asking for but it might worth considering.